# Does the Frechet Inception Distance (FID) consider color?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, datasets, inception, fid-score

I was wondering if the [Frechet inception distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_inception_distance)
for two colored datasets would be the same than the FID calculated for the same datasets converted to grayscale.

I know that it depends on the feature extraction, which is the Inception network. And that is the question, I don't fully understand the role of color in CNNs. I thought that all color information is lost in the feature extraction, and in this case I grayscale and colored datasets would produce the same FID. But I am not sure about that.

Comment: Can you please provide us with a link to an article that talks about this "Frechet Inception Distance". I know it exists, but not all people may know what exactly you're referring to. Moreover, it may be a good idea to tell us what you know about the FID. What is it usually used for? What's the equation to compute it? Generally, it's a good idea to [do a little bit of research before asking a question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi, I added more info